# compare two running scripts in python

Tags: python, debugging, compare

I'm debugging 2 scripts in python which should be the same up to variable names. But they have a difference. The output isn't the same.
The problem that both scripts handles large scale matrices, worse, the matrices might be slightly difference, because of a numerical error.
One way to solve it, is just to take 2 matrices and calculate the difference, and calculate the norm and see if it's closed to 0. the problem, that both scripts run in parallel, they are different processes so they don't share any memory.
Is there a way to debug the 2 scripts efficiently?  let's say share somehow the variables so they can be compared?
Of course, one might take variable one by one and export it to a file, but it's a long process.